# Node Js: Using a WebWorker to resize images

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am making a node.js application that can resize images. I am able to do this successfully with [jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp). However resizing an image is not asynchronous, and freezes the UI while resizing. I want to avoid this, so I tried using a webworker.

```
// main.js
var worker = new Worker(__dirname + '\\worker.js');

worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    if (e.data == 'done') { worker.terminate() } // Done
}, false);

worker.postMessage({'buff': buf, 'filename': filename}); // Start the worker
```

|

```
// worker.js
const Jimp = require('jimp'); // Oops, this doesn't work
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    resize(e.data.buf, e.data.filename);
}, false);

function resize(buf, filename) {
    Jimp.read(buf).then(image => {
        image.resize(1920, Jimp.AUTO);
        image.writeAsync(filename).then(cb => { self.postMessage('done') });
    });
}
```

What I found is that I cannot use node.js functions like `require()` in a webworker. How can I use Jimp in a webworker or resize an image in a different asynchronous way?

Edit: I am trying to use webworkify, copying the answer from @RubyJunk. When I try to create the worker I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.keys (<anonymous>)`. Does anyone know how to fix that?

Edit 2: I am using electron to create my Node.js app. They have a window property [(nodeIntegrationInWorker)](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/multithreading) that makes it seem like I can run Node.js functions in a Web Worker, but when I try to use require() it still tells me it is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [webworkify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworkify), and create your worker like so instead

```
var work = require('webworkify');
var worker = work(require('./worker.js');
```

and put your worker method into module.exports like so

```
const Jimp = require('jimp');

module.exports = function(self) {
    self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        resize(e.data.buf, e.data.filename);
    }, false);

    function resize(buf, filename) {
        Jimp.read(buf).then(image => {
            image.resize(1920, Jimp.AUTO);
            image.writeAsync(filename).then(cb => { self.postMessage('done') });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)` on `var worker = work(require('./worker.js');`. I'm guessing there is something wrong with how the worker method is defined?